# Problems sending variable data to other classes

Tags: c++, class, variables, constructor

//Items.h

```
class Items
{
public:
    Items();
    Items(string, string, double, int, int);
    //Item setters
    void setDesciption(string);
    void setSku(int);
    void setLocation(int);
    void setSupplier(string);
    void setCost(double);

    //Item getters
    string getDescription();
    int getSku();
    int getLocation();
    string getSupplier();
    double getCost();
private:
    //Item variables
    string _description;
    string _supplier;
    double _cost;
    int _sku;
    int _location;
};
```

//Constructor in the items class

```
Items::Items(string description, string supplier, double cost, int sku, int location)
{
    setDesciption(description);
    setSupplier(supplier);
    setCost(cost);
    setSku(sku);
    setLocation(location);
}
```

//This is the add items class
//This function is meant to set values for the variables in the items class by passing them through its default constructor.
//Now I tested calling the AddOrDeleteItems function in the in main(), and it works perfectly fine, but when I am trying it in another class file(Like the add items class), the variables in the items.h file are never set, and return their default values.

```
void AddOrDeleteItems::newItem()
{
    string description;
    string supplier;
    double cost;
    int sku;
    int location;
    //Run checks on things like sku length, location.
    cout << "Add a new product please enter the following.\n\n";
    cout << "Description: ";
    getline(cin, description);
    cout << "\nSupplier: ";
    getline(cin, supplier);
    cout << "\nCost: ";
    cin >> cost;
    cout << "\nSku: ";
    cin >> sku;
    cout << "\nLocation: ";
    cin >> location;

    Items ItemsObj(description, supplier, cost, sku, location);
}
```

## Edit add my getters and setters if that helps... (Also fixed spelling error in my setters and the rest of the code...lol)

```
//Item Setters

void Items::setDescription(string x) 
{ 
    _description = x;
}
void Items::setSku(int x) 
{ 
    _sku = x; 
}
void Items::setLocation(int x) 
{ 
    _location = x; 
}
void Items::setSupplier(string x) 
{ 
    _supplier = x; 
}
void Items::setCost(double x)
{
    _cost = x;
}

//Item Getters
string Items::getDescription() 
{
    return _description; 
}
int Items::getSku() 
{ 
    return _sku;
}
int Items::getLocation() 
{ 
    return _location; 
}
string Items::getSupplier() 
{ 
    return _supplier; 
}
double Items::getCost()
{
    return _cost;
}
```

Comment: lolz @ `setDesciption`.

Comment: Hahahaha cheers =P ill fix that but I don't think thats causing the issue.

Comment: @MaxMcgregor I am not sure how do you expect the variables to be set with the `newItem` method. It doesn't return the created item, and it doesn't take one as a parameter, and modify that. What it does is: creating a new `Items` object, which gets immediately destroyed upon returning from the function. What do you want that method to do, exactly?

Comment: Well its retail software thing Im making so when an item is created by the addnewitem function, I want those values to be returned and stored in the items.h class in those private variables, so that I can call on them later for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `AddOrDeleteItems::newItem()` you do `Items ItemsObj(description, supplier, cost, sku, location);` so you are declaring an instance of `Items` as a local variable in the stack of your function, and then you proceed to return from that function, completely forgetting that this local variable ever existed.  So, you are not really creating any new instance of `Items`.  Perhaps you meant this:

`return new Items(description, supplier, cost, sku, location);`

<sub>Also: that thing should probably be called "Item", not "Items".</sub>

<sub>Also: A class called "AddOrDeleteItems" is perverted as a notion and its name is making me feel nauseated.</sub>

Comment: If the return type is an object like that, then how do I declare the function type?

Comment: Yes, I realised the naming of the class was bad yesterday, but I wanted to get this problem solved first before looking at those changes.

Comment: `Items* AddOrDeleteItems::newItem();` but if you have questions about things as fundamental as this, then I think it would be more productive for you to be studying C++ books rather than painfully obtaining knowledge one tiny spoonful at a time by posting questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to first fix your names and stuff, and *then* post your question on stackoverflow, because we are people here, with sensitivities and feelings.  And you are hurting us.  C-:=

Comment: nawwww Im so sorry to hurt you xxx <3, with the way I personally learn, this seems to be the best method. I learn really well from breaking down complex problems (for me). Pouring over text books and endless tutorials just doesn't get saved in my memory ='c, where as when I make mistakes it sticks.

Comment: Okay Max, whatever floats your boat.  <3

Comment: _"Yes, I realised the naming of the class was bad yesterday, but I wanted to get this problem solved first before looking at those changes."_ Hmm yeah that's kinda backwards. Remember you're asking for our time for free. I realise you want your problem solved, but your urgency isn't our urgency so you ought to consider the value of our time too. If you think your code should be improved, do so _first_, so as not to force us to suffer its problems just because you're in a hurry for our free help! :) In this case though the "problems" seem completely trivial.